# is it really necessary to use redux in react? If not then how to manage states in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to know is it really necessary to use redux in react? If not then how to manage states in react and I also want to know is react hooks only enough to managing states.

Comment: Using Redux in a react application is not necessary at all as we have many other nice alternatives for example context API global state pieces and ReactQuery for data fetching and managing.

Answer (score 0):

no it is not required to use redux. that depends on your app needs.
please read the following post by redux author:
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

in small apps you can use context api to share data.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html